# How can I exclude crawlers to index certain page of my website using robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I tried this on my root `robots.txt`:

```
User-agent:  *
Allow: /
Disallow: /*&action=surprise

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.php
```

I would like to exclude from crawling urls like:

```
https://example.com/track&id=13&action=surprise&autoplay
```

From `access.log` file I see again some bots hitting those urls.

Am I doing anything wrong or it's just that some bots are not following my `robots.txt` settings?

Comment: I forgot the main tool! Google has a `robots.txt` tester in the Webmaster Console. My `robots.txt` looks correct however bad bots like Ahrefs ignore it.

Answer (score -1):

I have to say, not all bots will obey the rules and follow your robtos.txt.
you need add some anti-crawler tech to forbid the access...
such as:

1. check the user-agent
2. count the ip of bolts